# jquery scale losing position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have an absolute positioned img which i make it to appear using jquery scale effect...it works fine in firefox..in all other browsers this is what happens..

the img initially appears in a wrong position... the effect happens...then it comes to the position i have applied...is it a problem of scale effect...?

**Update**- the code

css..

```
<div id="uxcCircleContainerDiv" style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; width:177px; height:177px; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="/Images/Standard/Sample1.gif" id="uxcSample1" alt="" style="position:absolute;width:72px; height:72px; top:3px; left:3px; display:none;"/>
</div>
```

script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#uxcSample1').show('scale', 200);
</script>
```

hope i am clear now..

Comment: it would be more informative if you provide some code here

Comment: It seems to work just fine (in Chrome & IE): http://jsbin.com/abusi/3/

Comment: yes it does..! have no idea why my local host is not working..:( will check my code again..

and btw: the http://jsbin.com site is interesting..thanks..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for my case... dono if it is an inherent problem of scale effect...

the elements should be positioned with left as against using right... now my effects are working fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **div** to appear, why do you use the id of the **image** in your jQuery code ?